# Regex Group Capture to swap parts of the word places

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I am trying to write a function that moves consonants from the start of word to the end of the word using $2$1.

My code is below and I have researched the problem and attempted multiple variations of my function. Cannot understand why it is not working.

```
function groupCap(s){
  str = s.replace(/(^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+)(\.$)/, '$2$1');
  return str;
}
groupCap("map");
```

Comment: Start by describing what you think your regex is doing.

Comment: `s.replace(/^([b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+)(.*)/, '$2$1')`? `(\.$)` only matches a dot and the end of the string after it.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew, can you make it answer so I can marked it as answered?

Comment: I definitely meant .  (any character)  ,   not \.  (an actual dot). If it was not for this escape symbol I would have solved it myself. Sorry for making you debug my code, it was an accident. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `\.$` matches a dot and then asserts the position at the end of the string. You need to match and capture into Group 2 any chars there are in the string.

Use

```js
function groupCap(s){
  str = s.replace(/^([b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+)(.*)/, '$2$1');
  return str;
}
console.log(groupCap("map"));
```

Replace `.*` with `[^]*` if there can be line breaks in the string as `.` does not match line break chars, and `[^]` matches any char other than nothing, that is, all chars in the BMP plane.

Comment: Thanks for extra Regex info @Wiktor Stribiżew, much much appreciated. I still cannot believe I was using \. looking at it trying all sorts of variations not realising it is not a .